# Update values of a specific column of a specific row. Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a recyclerview cardholder that inflates using the values of 'NAME' from the table 'ORDERTABLE'. The cardholder also have an EditText which displays the values of column 'QUANTITY' in my SQLite database.

I also have a button to update the database for every changes in EditText.

I have this table ORDERTABLE

```
id      NAME         QUANTITY

 1      Order1          1
 2      Order2          1
 3      Order3          1
 4      Order4          1
```

Being more specific, how can i update the QUANTITY of Order2  on onButtonPressed with the new values of my EditText.

EDIT...

I have tried this code but nothing happened

Button to update values

```
public void addButtonClick(TextView tv_cardrowName_atc, TextView tv_currentPrice_atc, EditText et_quantity_atc, int position) {

            int thisQuantity = Integer.parseInt(et_quantity_atc.getText().toString());
            thisQuantity++;

            String orderName = tv_cardrowName_atc.getText().toString();
            String oldQuantity = et_quantity_atc.getText().toString();

            String newQuantity = String.valueOf(thisQuantity);
            sqliteCBLCAdapter.selectUpdateItem(orderName, oldQuantity, newQuantity);


            et_quantity_atc.setText(String.valueOf(thisQuantity));
        }
```

Update Method

```
public String selectUpdateItem(String orderName, String oldQuantity, String newQuantity) {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteCBLC.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME, SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY};
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteCBLC.TABLE_NAME, columns, SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME + " = '" + orderName + "'", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY);
        String order = cursor.getString(index1);
        String quantity = cursor.getString(index2);

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY, newQuantity);
        String[] whereArgs = {quantity};
        sqLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteCBLC.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY + " =? ", whereArgs);

        stringBuffer.append(order);

    }



    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code what you tried.?

Comment: This isn't a place to just write the code for you, post the code you have tried, and maybe someone can help fix your errors.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])

Comment: Hi, sorry. I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for you to achieve this would be to use  a SQL update query as follows:

From the SQLite Web Site:

The SQLite UPDATE Query is used to modify the existing records in a table. You can use a WHERE clause with UPDATE query to update selected rows, otherwise all the rows would be updated.

The syntax for the update query is as follows:

```
 UPDATE table_name
 SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
 WHERE [condition];
```

So in your case your sql update query would look some thing like this:

```
UPDATE ORDERTABLE SET QUANTITY = (INSERT VALUE OF YOUR EDIT TEXT) WHERE NAME =   'Order2'
```

You can then execute your query by using the execSQL() method of your SQLiteDatabase object that you have and passing in the sql query above as the string parameter.

Comment: Someone has already answered my question but I still want to try your code. But then it gave me an error 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INSERT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: 

UPDATE cblc_table SET Quantity = (INSERT 3) WHERE OrderName = Order1
........

This is my query..


            String updateQuery = "UPDATE " +SQLiteCBLC.TABLE_NAME+" SET "+SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY+" = (INSERT "+newQuantity+") WHERE "+SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME+" = "+orderName+"";
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(updateQuery);

Comment: @StevenF remove the insert and the parenthese around newQuantity so your new query should look something like this `"UPDATE " +SQLiteCBLC.TABLE_NAME+" SET "+SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY+" = "+newQuantity+" WHERE "+SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME+" = "+orderName+""; `

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this below code, In your case you while updating you are updating based on quantity, multiple order will have the same quantity. just check the order name and update it.

```
public void selectUpdateItem(String orderName, String oldQuantity, String newQuantity) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(order)) {
        return;
    }

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    final String whereClause = SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME + " =?";
    final String[] whereArgs = {
            orderName
    }; 

    // if you want to update with respect of quantity too. try this where and whereArgs below

    //final String whereClause = SQLiteCBLC.COL_ORDNAME + " =? AND " + SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY + " =?";
    //final String[] whereArgs = {
            //orderName, String.valueOf(oldQuantity)
    //};

    contentValues.put(SQLiteCBLC.COL_QUANTITY, newQuantity);

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteCBLC.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteCBLC.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
            whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: You are Welcome, If its works, you can accept this as an answer.